# Entity Framework Insert where FK Exists

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need some help with what should be fairly easy process. Can someone explain what I need to do to do this insert please?

InspectionPremiseTypeID has a fk to InspectionPremiseType.ID however, I have always just passed an int value where required. The (int)inspectionPremiseType is an int value which exists on the InspectionPremiseType table.

```
        efInspection newInspection = new efInspection();

        newInspection.Created = DateTime.Now;
        newInspection.CreatedBy = "Web";
        newInspection.ReturnHeaderID = ReturnID;
        newInspection.InspectionPremiseTypeID = (int)inspectionPremiseType;
        newInspection.PrePlanned = intPrePlanned;
        newInspection.FollowingComplaint = intComplaint;
        newInspection.FollowUp = intFollowUp;

        try
        {
            entities.AddToefInspections(newInspection);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When this runs I get this error

**Entities in 'dbEntities.efInspections' participate in the 'FK_Inspection_InspectionPremiseType' relationship. 0 related 'efInspectionPremiseType' were found. 1 'efInspectionPremiseType' is expected.**

I have also tried this

```
newInspection.InspectionPremiseTypeID = 
            entities.efInspectionPremiseTypes.Where(t => t.ID == (int)inspectionPremiseType).FirstOrDefault().ID;
```

but get this error (which is understandable)

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: What is the actual type of `inspectionPremiseType`?

Comment: Its actually an enum with the values matching whats stored in the InspectionPremiseType table.

Comment: I'd just like to add, I'm working on someone else's crappy code there is no model, its interacting directly with objects created via a model.edmx

Comment: Is there any chance that the inspectionPremiseType you're trying to add has an invalid ID? Maybe you're passing in null, or your database isn't exactly synced up with your code?

Comment: I have ruled out any mis-matches, and data exists where it should. The value being passed is valid on the foreign table.